# Atom keyboard shortcuts stopped working

Tags: atom-editor

Suddenly (more likely after update) some of my custom keyboard shortcuts defined in `keymap.cson` (**Edit > Keymap...**) stopped working. Has anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Apparently, one of my plugins (`emmnet`) used similar keyboard shortcut to the one that I defined in `keymap.cson`. So to save your time, check (**Edit > Preferences > Keybindings**) if any of your installed plugins has a keybindings that collides with your costume one.

Additionally, if in your OS you setup multiple keyboards layouts to support different languages then, please be sure that your application uses correct layout.